# Are there in OpenCV any Optical-Flow algorithms which rotate and/or scale-invariant?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, opencv3.0, opticalflow

In OpenCV we can use freatures to detection objects, and there are freatures wich are all translation-invariant and also:

- Which scale-invariant and rotate-invariant: SIFT, SURF, BRISK, FREAK, STAR
- And which not scale-invariant and rotate-invariant: ORB

Also in OpenCV there are Optical-Flow algorithms, which are all translation-invariant: `cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK`, `cv::calcOpticalFlowFarneback`, `cv::calcOpticalFlowSF`, `cv::DenseOpticalFlow::calc`, `gpu::BroxOpticalFlow` and other for GPU.

But are there in OpenCV any Optical-Flow algorithms which rotate and/or scale invariant?

Comment: cv::calcOpticalFlowPyrLK can deal with small rotation translation scaling... But if you are seeking something which will deal with 180 flipped image, you would head toward feature-based tracking not density based

Comment: ORB should be rotation invariant, too?!? You can always use a dense feature matching by choosing each single (sub)pixel to be a keypoint (maybe multiple scales) and describe it. But that would be horribly slow ;)

Comment: and FAST is no description so you can compute FAST features and describe them with sift/surf or any other descriptor

Comment: @Micka Yes I fixed it, ORB is rotate-invariant. I can't use dense optical-flow for real-time video :) But may be I can use sparse flow, for example, as follow: 9 adjacent points with window size 2x2 pixels instead of 1 point with window size 6x6 pixels. And for each frame I exclude each of 9 points which came out beyond the boundaries 9x9, and include new points. The percentage of matches = (9 - exclude points) / 9.